# How to avoid too much RAM memory usage

Tags: java, ram

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.3 with additional backports PPA to get LTS.

My three desktop PCs have an MSI H61M-P31W8 (MS-7788) motherboard, with Intel Core i5-3330 @ 3 GHZ, with 8 GB of RAM and two hard disk drives of 1 TB each one.

I want to use "xLogo", a Java version of the old Logo Programming Language, to get 3D figures in the screen.

But, when xLogo is working, I get a message about it is using almost the 90% of the computer RAM memory.

And I can confirm this is true, because the System Charge Monitor shows me the same thing: RAM Memory at 90%!

When I'm not using xLogo, I get this from "free -m" command:

```
              total usado libre compartido búfer/caché disponible
Memoria:        7673        4444        1837         138        1391        2828
Swap:          7848           1        7847
```

How can I get xLogo "eats" less RAM memory?

BTW: The System Charge Monitor is always shows me that my RAM Memory is around 60% to 65% used. Is it a normal value? Can I get more free RAM Memory? How?

Comment: I added the data about the 8 GB of RAM I have.

Comment: What is a normal value? I'm running UbuntuStudio 18.04.3 and my memory usage is about 1 GB at the moment (from Task Manager), having only firefox running with a few open tabs. Do you have any heavy applications running in the background? Does your system recognize the full amount of your RAM? Please add output of `free -m` to your question.

Comment: I added the data you were asking for. I don't know how much memory usage is expected as "normal", but... I guess it would be around a 25% of the total amount of RAM Memory, when we are not using anything but the basic Ubuntu Operating System.

Comment: Your RAM is recognized. That's good. As I said, my system does not use that much RAM, it's below 1GB when I close the browser. You may check with `top -o %MEM` which processes are eating your RAM, the processes will be listed sorted by memory usage, that may give you a clue.

Comment: According to the command: top -o %MEM, the main amount of memory used is about the process called: HAVP (more than 6 entries with 10.8 MB each one). I don't have any clue about that process!

Comment: I think you mean 10.8% each one, since 10.8 MB is a small amount. HAVP sounds like [antivirus](http://www.havp.org/). That's your memory-killer.

Comment: You're absolutely right, mook765! I uninstalled HAVP (which is a proxy antivirus, indeed), I restart the computer and... Now I have 36% of used RAM and 73% free RAM! It is a great difference!

Comment: @mook765 Can you write an answer for Juan to accept so this question doesn't keep reappearing for years as unanswered?

Comment: @mook765 Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an answer to this question, I'll sum up the information from the comments:

---

To find out what the problem is, we checked first if the installed RAM (8GB) is recognized by the system with

```
free -m
```

which showed total available RAM of 7673 MiB, so we know RAM is recognized.

In the second step we used

```
top -%MEM
```

which will list the running processes sorted by memory usage in percent.

Several processes, all named `HAVP` were using up to 60% of memory. This processes belong to 
[HAVP](http://www.havp.org/), a proxy antivirus application. Uninstalling `HAVP` from the system solved the problem with the high memory usage.